# NDK BUILD No such file or directory

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

I just used ANDROID SDK for the first time

I've setup everything according to the documentation and I'm now
trying to compile sample project but the ndk-build won't work.

I have NDK r10d installed, doc says no setup is needed, only need to
extract to some location. But when I run ndk-build I get the following
error message :

```
hamdi@hamdi-Lenovo-Ideapad-Flex-14 ~/AndroidStudioProjects/TEST $ ndk-build
make: /home/hamdi/Bureau/android-ndk-r10d/build/core/build-local.mk: No such file or directory
make: *** No rule to make target `/home/hamdi/Bureau/android-ndk-r10d/build/core/build-local.mk'.  Stop.
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you forget to add the NDK to your PATH variable? An explanation of how to do so can be found [here](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm).

Comment: No problem on the path .. I added the NDK folder to my Path variable
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/home/hamdi/Bureau/android-ndk-r10d/:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64

Answer (score 0):

are you sure that your NDK has been correctly extracted ? `/home/hamdi/Bureau/android-ndk-r10d/build/core/build-local.mk` is supposed to exist, check that it's actually there.